# Can Decorator + Reflection selectively create object trees representing individual function-call chain?

Tags: python

Given:

```
G = []

@Track
def f(x):
  a = g(x)
  b = h(x + 2)
  return a + b

def g(x)
  for n in range(2):
    i(x + n)

@Track
def h(x):
  return j(x) + 9

@Track
def i(x):
  return x + 10

@Track
def j(x):
  return 0
```

Is it possible to write & apply a decorator Track to f, h, i, j that will on each invocation of f, h, i, and j:

- instantiate a 'Call' object containing the function name 'f','h','i', and the arg- and return-values
- use reflection to search for the nearest similarly decorated function that called it (directly or indirectly) i.e. it would pass over calls to g(), since that is not @Tracked.
- appends the above 'Call' object to a 'children' list on the caller's 'Call' object, or to the global list G if there was no suitable caller found

For the code:

```
f(3)
j(3)
```

this should create the following connected object tree:

```
G
 -- Call(name='f',args=..., return=...)
    -- Call(name='i',args=..., return=...)
    -- Call(name='i',args=..., return=...)
    -- Call(name='i',args=..., return=...)
    -- Call(name='h',args=..., return=...)
      -- Call(name='j', args=..., return=...)
 -- Call(name='j', args=..., return=...)
```

I am stuck on the reflection / traverse the run-time stack frames part.

Thanks!

Comment: `traceback` will be helpful for traversion http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Comment: I did get the basic Track decorator to wrap its function, and capture args and return value, and stuff them into a Call object. Was stuck at how to locate the appropriate caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, it turns out like this

```
stack=[]
shift=0
def Track(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global shift
        stack.append([])
        el=stack[-1]
        el.append('%s -- call(name=%s,args=%s,kwargs=%s)' % ('    '*shift,func.__name__,args, kwargs))
        shift+=1
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        shift-=1
        el[0]+='return=%s)' % res
        return res
    return wrapper
```

For print:

```
for i in stack: print i[0]
```

show

```
 -- call(name=f,args=(3,),kwargs={})return=10)
     -- call(name=i,args=(3,),kwargs={})return=13)
     -- call(name=i,args=(4,),kwargs={})return=14)
     -- call(name=h,args=(5,),kwargs={})return=9)
         -- call(name=j,args=(5,),kwargs={})return=0)
 -- call(name=j,args=(3,),kwargs={})return=0)
```

But it is possible to agree with the other traceback will be helpful here,
although the traceback does not show the call parameters

Comment: This looks quite promising, I had not thought of Track maintaining its own stack. I will dig a bit deeper into using this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> instantiate a 'Call' object containing the function name 'f','h','i',
>   and the arg- and return-values

```
global_list_of_calls = defaultdict(list)

def Track(func):
    def _tracked(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        c = Call(func.__name__, args, kwargs, res)
        # do something with c, store it in a global container
        global_list_of_calls.append(c)
        return res
    return _tracked
```

> use reflection to search for the nearest similarly decorated function
>   that called it (directly or indirectly) i.e. it would pass over calls
>   to g(), since that is not @Tracked.

[`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) will be helpful here

> appends the above 'Call' object to a 'children' list on the caller's
>   'Call' object, or to the global list G if there was no suitable caller
>   found

Have in mind that when you store the calls with arguments and return values, they will not be garbage collected and your memory will grow. Also, If you store mutable objects (e.g., lists) what you see later in `Call` might not be the same you had when the `Call` was created

Comment: Thanks for the traceback link. It seems to be designed mostly for printed output, not the kind of usage I want. Will look closer.

Comment: check `extract_tb` and `extract_stack` functions